# Positive model bias but negative percent bias; why?

Tags: r, bias, rms

I'm comparing my training data with some predicted values using the `Metrics` package in R. When running the `bias` function, R returns a positive value, yet `percent bias` on the same data returns a negative value. What's going on?

Here's the data / code

```
    library(Metrics)

   act<-c(1.9,4.9,9.8,16.7,25.7,37.1,51,67.6,86.9,109.2,134.4,162.7,194.2,229,267.3,308.9,354.2,403.1,455.7,512.1,572.3,636.5,704.8,777.1,853.5,934.2,1019.1,1108.3,1202,1300.1,1402.7,1509.9,1621.8,1738.3,1859.5,1985.5,2120,2250,2390,2540,2690,2850,3010,3170,3340,3520,3700,3890,4080,4280,4480,4690,4910,5130,5350,5590,5820,6070,6320,6570,6830,7100,7370,7650,7940,8230,8520,8830,9140,9450,9770,10100,10440,10780,11120,11480,11840,12200,12580,12960,13340,13740,14140,14540,14960,15380,15800,16240,16680,17120,17580,18040,18510,18980,19460,19950,20450,20950,21460,21980,22500
)
pred<-c(1.97875829108291,4.87441981891739,9.68638775111453,16.5715610019699,25.67930370443,37.1518566832577,51.1247330448926,67.7270981873014,87.0821345330912,109.307391289271,134.515119536896,162.812592953937,194.302414474693,229.082809189018,267.247903784721,308.887992836402,354.089792244055,402.936680124749,455.508925460685,511.883904806941,572.13630736222,636.338328705897,704.55985350469,776.868627492241,853.330419024942,934.009170517296,1018.96714006013,1108.26503352494,1201.96212745776,1300.11638306574,1402.78455159986,1510.02227143699,1621.88415716467,1738.42388097194,1859.6942466494,1985.74725650196,2116.63417147754,2252.40556481493,2393.11136951426,2538.80091993338,2689.52298781326,2845.32581303603,3006.2571294187,3172.36418584602,3343.69376304571,3520.29218630943,3702.20533446276,3889.47864538753,4082.15711839972,4280.28531378638,4483.90734980477,4693.06689744706,4907.80717327391,5128.17093062023,5354.2004494764,5585.93752534835,5823.42345739967,6066.69903617919,6315.80453123726,6570.77967893403,6831.66367074316,7098.49514235406,7371.31216387616,7650.15223144847,7935.05226055761,8226.04858136782,8523.17693636612,8826.47248062599,9135.96978499278,9451.70284249437,9773.70507828014,10102.0093633917,10436.6480326688,10777.6529070933,11125.0553208748,11478.8861535822,11839.1758676215,12205.9545513676,12579.2519682491,12959.0976120921,13345.5207690259,13738.5505862523,14138.2161479844,14544.546558856,14957.5710351056,15377.3190038395,15803.820210675,16237.1048360691,16677.2036206347,17124.1479997485,17577.9702477533,18038.703632058,18506.3825774391,18981.0428408469,19462.7216970188,19951.4581352044,20447.2930673051,20950.2695477306,21460.4330052778,21977.8314873327,22502.515916701
)
    bias(act , pred)

       [1] 1.04888e-05

    percent_bias(act, pred)*100

       [1] -0.02422372
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the error defined as:

$$e_i = a_i - p_i$$

Some of those errors are positive (prediction too low), and some of them are negative (prediction too high). On average, they are too low (i.e. the bias is positive).

You then have the percentage error defined as $e_i/a_i$. If you tend to have predictions which are too high *when the actual is small* (so a large negative percentage error, since all your actuals are positive), and too low *when the actual is large* (a small positive percentage error), the average of the percentage error can be negative.

In general, the bias depends on the distribution of the $e_i$, but the percentage bias depends on the joint distribution of the $e_i$ and the $a_i$.

Comment: That's great. Thank you